# amp-fx-parallax demo not working on my server

Tags: amp-html

I copy exactly the code from AMP Playground into my php file on my server from here:
https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-fx-parallax%2Fsource%2F

But it doens't work there and Google Dev Tools say:

```
Experiment "amp-fx-parallax" is disabled.
```

But it is exactly the same code like in the AMP Playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amp-fx-parallax is still [experimental](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/tools/experiments). You can enable the experiment locally by entering: `AMP.toggleExperiment('amp-fx-parallax')` in your browser's developer console.